# Get the day of week text from the day number in italian or in any language

Tags: php

I have created some code to get the day of the week from dayNumber

```
$weekday_text = date( 'l', strtotime( '+3 days', strtotime( 'Monday' ) ) );
echo $weekday_text;

Outputs: "Thursday"
```

It is working only for english language but not for other different languages.
What I need is "It has to work for other languages too but it don't".
For eg:( Italian language) I have used below code for Italian language to display the day in Italian language like ( "giovedì" ) but its not outputting anything.

```
echo date( 'l', strtotime( '+3 days', strtotime( 'lunedì' ) ) );
```

Comment: `strtotime` can only handle English textual date representations. So you need to translate your Italian day name to English somehow.

Answer (score 1):

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and  strftime() functions instead of  date().

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT');
echo strftime("%A");
```

http://www.phpnews.it/articoli/ottenere-date-in-italiano/